# How to make my C# windows application lightweight?

Tags: c#, performance, resources, dispose

Guys I have developed a ticket management system in C# windows forms application. Now this is the first time I have developed any application that might be used in real world (my school may implement it).

As my school is not that rich and mostly run by charity, so the technology they use is pretty old (Pentium 4 pcs with windows XP having maximum of 1 gb RAM), so I need to make my application as light-weight as possible i.e. it should not be resource hungry. (I have developed this app on dual core laptop with 4 gb RAM, and I haven't come up with any errors yet regarding to resources but considering the low config of target PC(s) I want to be sure)

I have about 25 forms in my application, in which 7-8 have DataGridViews in them. Others are just filled with labels and textboxes for taking input or display data - nothing fancy.

As this is my first complete application I am not sure how it will perform in the performance department. I read somewhere that in .Net applications you have to call dispose() method whenever the form is closer or else the garbage wont be collected and same goes for `DataGridView`. Is that true? because throughout the application I **haven't** used Dispose anywhere. Should I be worried?

If `Dispose()` is necessary, where and when should I call it? on FormClosed event? If a form has DataGridView should I dispose it first and then dispose form or is directly disposing the form enough? Also if you "experienced programmers" could point out some good practices to make application less resource dependent and less crash-prone then that would be great.

Comment: Regarding Windows XP: Make sure that you build the application on .NET 4 or lower, because Windows XP doesn't support .NET 4.5!

Comment: Find an average computer and try the program on it. See how it works. If it works OK then nothing needs to be done; there is no point in optimising just for the sake of optimising. If it does not work OK then use a debugger or programs like Task Manager to learn why the performance is poor. Then focus your optimisation efforts on that.

Comment: @Mathew Yes, my application targets framework 4.0 :)

Comment: @AdrianHHH : I guess I will have to find some old PC then. `Trial and Error` all the way :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware C# (and .NET) is managed. So your code and objects will get disposed of.

A good trick, is to look at using [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks. These are especially useful around data connections.

The other obvious piece of advise is to actually run it on the machines you will be using it and, and see how it performs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *C# (and .NET) is managed. So your code and objects will get disposed of.* What do you meant by this?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well I have already used `using` block in all SMTP and data connections.

Comment: Managed doesn't mean you have to forget about resource consumption/allocation. Every single `IDisposable` object must be disposed and yes, most of times with `using` you'll do it (but it's not always possible so you may need to implement `IDisposable` too, it's a _viral_ contract).

Comment: Yes, I should have been a bit more explicit. You should still ensure you dispose when necessary, and implement `IDisposable`. +1 Adriano; thanks for making me clarify.

Comment: That is what I am asking. When and how should I implement `IDisposable` ? how do I know which objects to dispose ?

Comment: If you use something like Visual Studio you can often see whether that object implements `dispose()`. If it does, then placing that in a `using` block, they *should* automatically be disposed on close. In other circumstances, such as creating your own classes and objects, consider what types of objects you are using; and whether you can implement `IDisposable` on your class also. It is difficult to provide a concrete answer, without seeing your entire application.

Comment: @RichardSimpson I am infact using Visual Studio 2012. I see. Thank you for responding to my queries.